# Questions on how install Android

Tags: android, installation

I'm trying to install the android SDK on my computer, but a bunch of weird things are happening. My main problem is when I try to install the Android 4.0.3 package. When I do, it says that nothing has been installed. When I look into the installation report, this is what comes up:

```
Preparing to install archives
Downloading Android SDK Tools, revision 19
File not found: C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\temp\tools_r19-windows.zip (Access is denied)
Downloading SDK Platform Android 4.0.3, API 15, revision 3
File not found: C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\temp\android-15_r03.zip (Access is denied)
Downloading Samples for SDK API 15, revision 2
File not found: C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\temp\samples-15_r02.zip (Access is denied)
Downloading Sources for Android SDK, API 15, revision 2
File not found: C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\temp\sources-15_r02.zip (Access is denied)
Downloading Google USB Driver, revision 4
File not found: C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\temp\usb_driver_r04-windows.zip (Access is denied) 
Skipping 'ARM EABI v7a System Image, Android API 15, revision 2'; it depends on 'SDK Platform Android 4.0.3, API 15, revision 3' which was not installed.
Skipping 'Intel x86 Atom System Image, Android API 15, revision 1'; it depends on 'SDK    Platform Android 4.0.3, API 15, revision 3' which was not installed.
Skipping 'Google APIs, Android API 15, revision 2'; it depends on 'SDK Platform Android 4.0.3, API 15, revision 3' which was not installed.
Skipping 'HTC OpenSense SDK, Android API 15, revision 2'; it depends on 'SDK Platform Android 4.0.3, API 15, revision 3' which was not installed.
Skipping 'ICS_R1, Android API 15, revision 1'; it depends on 'SDK Platform Android 4.0.3, API 15, revision 3' which was not installed.
Done. Nothing was installed.
```

In this, it says that access was denied when it tried to access a certain file. How do I solve this?

Comment: try with sdk at other path like in D: drive... where no issue of writing Access

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you are apparently using NetBeans, not Eclipse:

Right-click on your Android SDK Manager -> Run as Administrator.

This is assuming you're using Windows OS.

Answer (score 1):

Close your eclipse.

Then **Right Click on eclipse icon --> Run as Administration.**

this may solve your problem or see [this](http://developer-android.blogspot.in/2012/06/how-to-install-android-step-by-step.html) step by step installation guide

Comment: I'm using netbeans, not eclipse

Comment: then Right Click on Netbeans icon --> Run as Administration

Answer (score 0):

If you are on an office computer, you may not have the necessary rights anymore to do this. Try d:

Comment: i'm not on an office computer. This is my personal computer.